# Reading txt file and storing every 4 lines of text into an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a program that reads a text file. The text file contains data as follows:

Number :    1    I.D :  xyz

1   abc 3.2         4.0389                 0.3815  2    def 24
    25.2395     CTO        0.8719  4    ghi 2           1.9139                 0.2855

Number :    2    I.D :  abc

1   lfr 3.2         4.0389                 0.3815  2    tyu 24
    25.2395     CTO        0.8719  4    lui 2           1.9139                 0.2855

I need my program to read the file and store each section starting from "Number" and ending in the last line where the number "4" is at the beginning of that line and store it into an array. 
The lines are splitted using the following RegEx "[\s\t\n]+" 
In other words the array should look like this:

> Array[0]= Number Array[1]= : Array[2]= 1 Array[3]= I.D Array[4]= :
>   Array[5]= xyz Array[6]= 1 Array[7]= abc Array[8]= 3.2 Array[9]= 4.0389
>   Array[10]= 0.3815 Array[11]= 2 Array[12]= def Array[13]= 24 Array[14]=
>   25.2395 Array[15]= CTO Array[16]= 0.8719 Array[17]= 4 Array[18]= ghi Array[19]= 2 Array[20]= 1.9139 Array[21]= 0.2855
>
> Next iteration in the loop again:
>
> Array[0]= Number Array[1]= : Array[2]= 2 Array[3]= I.D Array[4]= :
>   Array[5]= lfr Array[6]= 1 Array[7]= abc Array[8]= 3.2 Array[9]= 4.0389
>   Array[10]= 0.3815 Array[11]= 2 Array[12]= tyu Array[13]= 24 Array[14]=
>   25.2395 Array[15]= CTO Array[16]= 0.8719 Array[17]= 4 Array[18]= lui Array[19]= 2 Array[20]= 1.9139 Array[21]= 0.2855

I have tried different ways to approach this problem, but I just don`t know how to do it that way.

The problem exactly is:
I need to compare values that are in different lines. This will work easier if the program reads 4 lines and store that into the same array. That way I know what array elements I am comparing. I only know how to read the array line by line and that doesn`t always work for what I need it for because when the program iterates through the array once it goes to the next line of the file I cannot compare values that were in the previous line or values that are after the line that is being read.

This is what I have right now:

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/yesmil_03/Desktop/NetBeansProjects//123.txt"));
    String line = null;
    String[] value = null;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.isEmpty() || line.trim().equals("") || line.trim().equals("\n")) {
            continue;
        }
        value = line.split("[\\s\\t\\n]+");

        int index = 0;
        for (String s : value) {
            System.out.println("values[" + index + "] = " + s);
            index++;
        }
    }
    br.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error!");
}
```

This is the output of my code:

```
values[0] = Number
values[1] = :
values[2] = 1
values[3] = I.D
values[4] = :
values[5] = xyz
values[0] = 1
values[1] = abc
values[2] = 3.2
values[3] = 4.0389
values[4] = 0.3815
values[5] = 2
values[6] = def
values[7] = 24
values[0] = 
values[1] = 25.2395
values[2] = CTO
values[3] = 0.8719
values[4] = 4
values[5] = ghi
values[6] = 2
values[7] = 1.9139
values[8] = 0.2855
values[0] = Number
values[1] = :
values[2] = 2
values[3] = I.D
values[4] = :
values[5] = abc
values[0] = 1
values[1] = lfr
values[2] = 3.2
values[3] = 4.0389
values[4] = 0.3815
values[5] = 2
values[6] = tyu
values[7] = 24
values[0] = 
values[1] = 25.2395
values[2] = CTO
values[3] = 0.8719
values[4] = 4
values[5] = lui
values[6] = 2
values[7] = 1.9139
values[8] = 0.2855
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This question is almost in the correct format for stack overflow. It shows sample code, the output you are expecting, and expresses that you have a problem.  However, this post is : a)unclear in what the problem is exactly, and b) unclear on the current output. This may be why you are having a problem. Please explain the current output and what the problem is and we will be better able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what you want you should split your line at every 1 or more spaces so:

```
value = line.split("[\\s\\t\\n]+");
```

Should be changed to:

```
value = line.split("\\s+");
```

Also, you were not storing the strings. This piece of codes produces the output you requested

```
String[] array = new String[200];
    int index = 0;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./src/cenas.txt"));
        String line = null;
        String[] value = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.isEmpty() || line.trim().equals("")
                    || line.trim().equals("\n")) {
                continue;
            }
            value = line.split("\\s+");

            for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                array[index++] = value[i];
                System.out.println("value[" + index + "] = " + value[i]);
            }
        }
        br.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
    }
```

Output:

value[1] = Number value[2] = : value[3] = 1 value[4] = I.D value[5] = : value[6] = xyz value[7] = 1 value[8] = abc value[9] = 3.2 value[10] = 4.0389 value[11] = 0.3815 value[12] = 2 value[13] = def value[14] = 24 value[15] = 25.2395 value[16] = CTO value[17] = 0.8719 value[18] = 4 value[19] = ghi value[20] = 2 value[21] = 1.9139 value[22] = 0.2855 value[23] = Number value[24] = : value[25] = 2 value[26] = I.D value[27] = : value[28] = abc value[29] = 1 value[30] = lfr value[31] = 3.2 value[32] = 4.0389 value[33] = 0.3815 value[34] = 2 value[35] = tyu value[36] = 24 value[37] = 25.2395 value[38] = CTO value[39] = 0.8719 value[40] = 4 value[41] = lui value[42] = 2 value[43] = 1.9139 value[44] = 0.2855

Comment: Thank you so much! This actually puts everything into the same array. However, how would I make it start again with array element zero when it reaches to this line "Number : 2 I.D : abc". SO instead of having 44 elements in the array I would have 21 elements for each iteration of the loop. How can I do that?

Comment: depends, if they all have the same size, you can just check if (index == 21) index = 0;

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I got it now and it works. Thanks a lot! @pedromss